# Is it okay to ask questions on ELL even if you're not learning English as a second language?

Tags: discussion

As I'm a high school student, I was wondering if it's okay for me to ask questions on ELL about grammar and so forth although English is my first language. If so, which topics can I ask questions about?

Comment: In [this discussion](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/769) about the difference between [english.se] and ELL, someone said "ELL is about helping people learn English". Just because English is our first language doesn't mean that we know everything there is to know about it! Folks who are learning English as a foreign language probably have a better understanding of English grammar and "the rules" than I ever will, and as a native speaker, I can help with slang, idioms, finding the right word, whether something "sounds natural" etc. It's a win-win :)

Comment: You certainly can ask a question on ELL, but the answers should be written for English Learners, and that primarily means L2 learners.  You should not expect the same kind of answer on ELL that you might get on ELU.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should try to ask questions that would be of interest to those who are learning the language as a second language.

We're not here to help you with your homework, but if you can couch your question in a way such that the learning community at large will benefit from the question and its eventual answers, then you can ask it here.

That said, since you are a native speaker, I'd expect your questions would be written with great care and display exemplary grammar.

As for what topics are allowed, do you have any specific questions that aren't answered in the site's [Help Center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help)? There are links there that explain what topics are allowed, and what kinds of questions you should avoid asking.

Incidentally, I'm a native speaker, and I've asked a couple questions on ELL. You can [have a look at those](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/113/j-r?tab=questions) if you'd like.